# I can't figure out why R thinks that my dataset contains element pair duplicats in my dataset?

Tags: r

When I run my fixed effects regression as shown below I get an error saying that I have duplicates within my dataset. This is the error: "Error in pdim.default(index[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVxUj.png)], index[[2]]) :    duplicate couples (id-time)"!

```
fe_distance <- plm(total_trip_distance ~ apparentTemperature+summary+AREA+POPULATION+bar+nightclub+hospital+social_facility, data = regression1, model= "within", index=c("ZIPCODE", "time"))
```

[image: Here is an image of my dataframe]

To form the dataset I grouped by ZIPCODE and time so I don't understand how I could possibly get duplicates within the elements. I was thinking it could be because of the type of variable that the variable was stored as, however changing that doesn't seem to solve my error.

Any recommendations would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can check for any duplicate pairings between zipcode and time via `sum(duplicated(regression1[,c('ZIPCODE','time')]))`. If this is greater than 0, then you do have duplicates, and should check to see if there is anything unexpected in your original data (or any errors that could have resulted in the grouping step).